# Determining $\gcd(94, 27)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility

I want to determine $\gcd(94, 27)$.  Using the Euclidean algorithm, I got
\begin{align}
94 &= 27 (3) + 13 \\
\implies 27 &= 13 (2) + 1 \\
\implies \;\;2 &= 2 (1)
\end{align}

Does this mean the GCD is $2$?  Clearly $2$ doesn't divide $27$, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't it the last non-zero remainder that is the GCD. In your case that would be 1 (from $27=13(2)+1$).

Comment: $27=13(2)+1$ leads to $13=13(1)$.

Comment: $(94,27) = (13,27) = (13,1) = 1$ according to your steps.

Comment: You must take the last remainder which is not equal to $0$ so here it's $1$

Comment: 13=13*1+0 => gcd is 1(for last row)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the *last non-zero remainder* is the GCD, not the quotient corresponding to the expression with zero remainder.  To highlight, that is the red/boxed number below:
\begin{align}
94 &= 27 (3) + 13 \\
27 &= 13 (2) + \color{red}{\boxed{1}} \\
13 &= 13  (1) + 0
\end{align}

For another example, consider $\gcd(45, 81)$:
\begin{align}
81 &= (1)45 + 36 \\
45 &= (1)36 + \color{red}{\boxed{9}}  \\
36 &= (4)9  + 0
\end{align}

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Using the shorthand notation for gcd:
$$(94, 27) = (13,27) = (27,13) = (1, 13) = 1,$$
so $94$ and $27$ are relatively prime. In your work, you incorrectly pulled the $2$ from the second line to work with; you wanted the $13$.